# Is there any Zsh plugins to format/collapse any JSON logs displayed through the terminal?

Tags: json, zsh, oh-my-zsh

So I have basically a server running locally on my computer. I sometime need to enable verbose of logs to the maximum, for some debug purpose.

The thing is, when I'm logging everything, I'm surged by a lot of (and big) JSON objects logs which make difficult to read anything.

I wish I could install a Zsh plugin which automatically detect JSON logs and collapse them, so that I can click on the json log which I want to see easily. If it could also put some colors, would be even better !

Do you know any existing Zsh plugin which can do this ? Google didn't help me to find out something.

Thanks !

Comment: Why not use a json parser like [tag:jq]?

Comment: @0stone0 well my server is running with Node JS, not sure jq fits my needs. If it actually does, do you have a link to some documentation ?

Comment: Nodejs? Then why is this tagged zsh? Thought you'd need a CLI solution. Anyway: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: I'm expecting something that intercepts all logs, processing any formatting (in case it detects json content) then it display it in the terminal with some UX interactions (button to uncollapse or copy the json).